# how to create horizontal list inside vertical scroll in react native for IOS and android

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to create view like following image:
I am beginner in react native.
=> Which control i have to use?
=>How to design App architecture?

Comment: Please put some code if you are facing some issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggested Model Type**

```
[{
   type:"MOST_SEARCHED",
   data:[],//your data comes here for horizontal row's
   orientation:'horizontal'
 },
 {
   type:"BLOGS",
   data:[],//your data comes here for horizontal row's
   orientation:'horizontal'
 }]
```

After this you need to design the View (Inner component)

```
 _wallList=(item)=>{
 return( <Carousel
        data={item.data}
        extraData={this.state}
        inactiveSlideScale={1}
        renderItem={(item) => {
                if (wallType === MOST_SEARCHED) {
                   this._renderMostSearched()// view for most searched
                }   
        }}
        sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH}
        itemWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH - 32}
  />)
 }
```

Outer flatlist

```
  <FlatList
        ref={(c) => {
              this._flatList = c
            }}
        style={{overflow: 'visible'}}
        directionalLockEnabled={true}
         data={this.state.data}
         renderItem={(item) => (this._wallList(item))}
         refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
         onRefresh={this._refreshHome}
         onScroll={this.handleScroll} />
```

Comment: Thanks @ Rajat for suggestion.